# doctrine QueryBuilder arithmetic operation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I am trying to do an arithmetic operation with doctrine Query Builder and assign the result to an alias.
Following is an example from [geeksengine](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/arithmetic-operations.php) that I'd like to "convert" to doctrine QueryBuilder:

```
/*
Query 1: This query calculates the total price before  discount and after discount for each order item.
*/
SELECT order_id,
   product_id, 
   unit_price * quantity AS "regular_price", 
FROM order_details;
```

This is what I started with:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('o')
             ->addSelect('o.unit_price * o.quantity AS regular_price')
             ->from('Test\Model\Entity\OrderEntity', 'o');
```

But this throws an exception:

```
RuntimeException
Not all identifier properties can be found in the ResultSetMapping: id
```

I guess, it's because `regular_price` is not part of the database - so it can't be mapped.

I can get it done with pure DQL but for some reasons I have to stick with the QueryBuilder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arithmetic Expr function `prod` ([doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)), then assign the result to your alias:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('o')
             ->addSelect($queryBuilder->expr()->prod('o.unit_price', 'o.quantity').' AS regular_price')
             ->from('Test\Model\Entity\OrderEntity', 'o');
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but I still get the same exception

Comment: Could it come from another part of your code? I don't see anything related to `id` in this part...

Comment: That was my first thought as well. But if I skip the line with addSelect() everything works fine.